# Selecteditem for Combobox not working inside datagrid

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a Datagrid, in that one of the the column is a Combobox. The issue is: SelectedItem will work well if Combobox is outside the Datagrid but wont work if same code of combobox is inside the grid. Here is the code.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Grid.Row="2" Background="White" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=lvwPPVEvents}" Margin="0,0,0,1.875" >
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.TestNumberofInstallments}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.TestInstall, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGrid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredOrderedEvents,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding EventSelected}" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
              CellStyle="{StaticResource ClearlstItmContainerStyle}" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" MaxHeight="125"
              AlternationCount="2" SelectionMode="Single" Background="White"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,2"
                  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="White" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=stackPanel}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="50" Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Path= Status}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Order ID" Binding="{Binding Path= EventID}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="140" Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Path= Desc}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="120" Header="Date / Time" Binding="{Binding Path= StartDate}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Channel" Binding="{Binding Path= Channels}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="50" Header="Cost" Binding="{Binding Path= Cost,StringFormat=N2}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <!--<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Install" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding colNumberofInstallments}"/>-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Install">
                    <!--<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <wpf:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding NumberOfInstallments}" FormatString="N0" Increment="1" Maximum="{Binding Max}" Minimum="1"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>-->

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding NumberOfInstallments}"/>-->
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.TestNumberofInstallments,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.TestInstall, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="37" Header="Max" Binding="{Binding Path= Max}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns >
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

It wont work, mainly because DataGridTemplateColumn is not part of the visual tree. So the RelativeSource doesn't really mean anything on that context.

You can do however simple hackery:

```
    <DataGrid.Resources>
    <TextBlock x:Key="TempHack" DataContext="{YOUR ACTUAL BINDING HERE}"/>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
```

and then you can reference it like this:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource TempHack}}" />
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You can use `RelativeSource` bindings from a `DataGridTemplateColumn` just fine because it is a template, so the actual bindings don't occur until the template gets used. You might be thinking of a `ContextMenu`, which is not part of the `VisualTree`

Comment: Actually you may be partially correct. I was quite surprised to find that using `ElementName` in a `DataGridTemplateColumn` did not appear to work, however using a `RelativeSource` in the a `DataGridTemplateColumn` works just fine :)

Comment: Actually, what I said is correct. Let me rephrase. Yes, the actual CellTemplate is part of the visual tree, however DataGridTemplateColumn is not. If you try to bind it's Header/With property through visual tree, it wont work. Although yes, my "information" does not apply to original poster, because he is actually using CellTemplateColumn, which is part of the visual tree. So yes, the relativeSource should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different controls that can be considered a `UserControl`, so I suspect you are not getting the right `UserControl` with your `RelativeSource` binding

I'd suggest using your UserControl's full class name instead of just trying to find the closest `UserControl` in the VisualTree

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.TestNumberofInstallments, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.TestInstall, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}}" />
```

I did a quick test and it seems to work just fine, however it surprised me that I couldn't use `ElementName` in my binding. Perhaps [ChrisDD is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12060285/302677) about not being able to use `ElementName` in a `DataGridTemplateColumn` because of something to do with the `VisualTree`, but you can definitely use `RelativeSource` in a `DataGridTemplateColumn`

```
<StackPanel x:Name="RootPanel">

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=RootPanel, Path=DataContext.Test}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=RootPanel, Path=DataContext.SelectedTest}"
              DisplayMemberPath="TestValue"/>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Test}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Path=DataContext.Test}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedTest}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="TestValue"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

The one thing you should be careful of is WPF compares objects by reference, not value, so the `SelectedItem` has to point to the exact same reference in memory as an item in the `ItemsSource`, or it won't be considered a match and get selected.

For example,

```
ItemsSourceProperty = new ObservableCollection<SomeObject>()
{
    new SomeObject(1),
    new SomeObject(2),
    new SomeObject(3)
};

SelectedItemProperty = ItemsSourceProperty.FirstOrDefault(); // Works
SelectedItemProperty = new SomeObject(1); // Won't work
```

Comment: But same Usercontrol used as relative source in ItemsSource works perfectly fine. The combobox gets populated. The same Usercontrol used as relative source in SelectedItem doesn't work?  Mean while I tried giving name to my Usercontrol and use it as ElementName... It doesn't work

Comment: @NavneetDuggal How are you setting the `SelectedItem` initially? WPF compares items by reference, so the `SelectedItem` needs to point to the exact same reference in memory as an item in the `ItemsSource`. I did a quick test on my own and it works fine. I'll update my answer with the code used - perhaps it will help you out.

Comment: Rachel, Thanks for your effort.Actually SelectedItem is correctly bound.Problem is,when from UI I change the selection of the comboBox in the grid,SelecteItem's setter is not fired. But since Combobox outside the grid is also bound to same properties and if I change the selection of outside Combobox= SelectedItem's setter gets fired. Since SelectedItem now changed so selectedItem inside the combobox is also changed.Thus it means that property binding is working but selection changed is not getting fired.I even tried SelectedIndex and Selection change event in the code behind.Nothing working.

Comment: @NavneetDuggal That's strange, the sample I have here is correctly updating the source whenever I changed either the DataGrid's ComboBoxes or the top ComboBox. Can you provide the code for the `SelectedItem` and `ItemsSource` properties in your question?

Comment: Remove the UpdateSourceTrigger statement. You can also remove Mode=TwoWay from SelectedItem since it is twoway by default. Alternatively, you can also try binding every other ComboBox SelectedItem to the first outer ComboBox SelectedItem. 

You might want to remove SelectedItem definition from the inner CHeckBox and see what happens when you use IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" attribute.